# change password in codeigniter with throws error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When i press submit for the current password,new password and confirm password, it keep showing error[Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Current Password.(checkCurrentPassword)] beside the current password's text field. Please help, thank you!

Below is my controller:

```
public function chgpass()
        {
    //$this->load->view('chgpass');
    //$this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Current Password','trim|required|max_length[20]|min_length[6]|callback_checkCurrentPassword|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('npassword','New Password','trim|required|max_length[20]|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('copassword','Confirm Password','trim|required|max_length[20]|min_length[6]');


              if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){     
                       $this->load->view('chgpass');
                        }else{
             $this->load->model('Form_model');
                 $this->load->view('chgpass');
                 $query = $this->Form_model->checkCurrentPassword($this->input->post('cpassword'));

             if($query){
                $query = $this->Form_model->saveNewPassword($this->input->post('npassword'));

                    if($query){
                    $this->session->sess_destroy();
                    $data['error']='Password Change Successfully!';
                                                $this->load->view('chgpass',$data);
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                                                redirect('main/chgpass');
                }
             }
           }
         }


       }
```

Below is my model:

```
public function checkCurrentPassword($cpassword)
{
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
    $this->db->where('password',$this->input->post('cpassword'));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){

            return true;

        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('checkCurrentPassword','Wrong old password!');
            return false;
        }

}

public function saveNewPassword($npassword)
{
 $data = array(
               'password' => $npassword
               );
 $this->db->where('id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
 $this->db->where('password',$this->input->post('cpassword'));
 $query = $this->db->update('users',$data);
 if($query){
    return true;
 }else{
    return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
//controller

```
public function chgpass()
        {
if ($this->input->post()) {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '<br />');
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $resetPasswordArray = array(
                    'Password' => md5(md5($time_now) . md5($this->input->post('resetPassword'))),
                    'Last_Updated' => $time_now,
                    'Record_Created' => $time_now
                );
                if ($this->Consumer_model->updatepassword($this->input->post('id'), $resetPasswordArray)) {
                    parent::json_output(["id" => $this->input->post('id'), "code" => 1]);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                echo validation_errors();
                die;
            }
        }
        return "0";
}
//model
function updatepassword($user_id, $user_details_array) {
        return $this->db->where('id', $user_id)->update('tablename', $user_details_array);
    }
```